# Stackoverflow Sentiment Search Engine

Tags: app, website

**Sentiment analysis...**

Generally speaking, sentiment analysis aims to determine the attitude of a speaker or a writer with respect to a topic or the overall contextual polarity of a document. The attitude may be his or her judgment or evaluation affective state (that is to say, the emotional state of the author when writing), or the intended emotional communication (that is to say, the emotional effect the author wishes to have on the reader). A basic task in sentiment analysis is classifying the polarity of a given text in a document, sentence, or feature/aspect level. Whether the expressed opinion in a document, a sentence or an entity feature/aspect is positive, negative, or neutral. Advanced, "beyond polarity" sentiment classification looks, for instance, at emotional states such as "angry," "sad," and "happy."

**Information overload...**

Information overload refers to the difficulty a person can have understanding an issue and making decisions that can be caused by the presence of too much information. As the world moves into a new era of globalization, an increasing number of people are connecting to the Internet to conduct their own research and are given the ability to produce as well as consume the data accessed on an increasing number of websites.

**What is this site for?**

Stackoverflow sentiment search engine is designed to solve the second using the first one. It utilises stackoverflow API to get a bunch of posts based on user input and prints on the screen the ones that have more positive comments/answers than the rest of them. uClassify (is a free web service where you can easily create your own text classifiers. You can also directly use classifiers that are shared by the community) API is used to classify the text using custom made classifiers.

[Link]

```
http://83.212.101.140/
```

it is opensource and the code will be public soon!